# linux. many file descriptors when call sys_clone

Tags: c++, linux, clone

am create 400 threads using clone with flags SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM

and $ losf | wc -l show me 600 000 opened descriptors after runnning

what i need to do?

Comment: Any particular reason to use `clone` rather than `fork`? Also, we have no idea what you need to do. Like in Alice in Wonderland: “Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?” “-That depends a good deal on where you want to get to”

Comment: 400 threads seems really excessive. Why do you need that many? This seems like a scheduling overhead nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `CLONE_FILES` you probably don't need to do anything.

`lsof` shows the sum of file descriptors held by each thread, even though these different threads are sharing a single set of file descriptors on the backend. So if you have a 1000 threads with 100 file descriptors shared, it will appear to be 100,000 file descriptors open if you just check with `lsof`.

Check `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr` to see the actual number of file descriptors your system has open.

As for whether a tool exists that can determine a list of unique file descriptors and what processes/threads have them open, I'm not sure. I've never needed to do that myself, but it appears to be a problem no one has yet scratched.

Comment: yes it create many descriptors. but limit for process 1 million. i cant create more than 5000 threads

Comment: Are you bumping up against a system limit? run `ulimit -a` in a terminal and see if there are limits there you're bumping into?